# Can we have a default message with a concise faq posted when a question is closed as Off Topic?

Tags: feature-request, off-topic

Forgive me if this has been suggested before. I searched around but I wasn't able to find anything similar.

When a question is migrated to another site, a default message is posted with something like `"This question was migrated from ....."`

What about something similar when the question is closed as off topic? I am asking because I routinely see comments along the lines of.

> Welcome to the *[site]* StackExchange. This site is for
>   __________________.  questions like this are strictly off-topic. You can read our [faq] for more information. If you have a question
>   regarding __________________ free to ask it. We will be glad to help
>   you.

What if something like that could be automatically posted when a question was closed as off topic, instead of the generic off topic message? Each site would needs its own, but most likely it could be taken from the FAQ itself.

I know this isn't a huge feature, and more of a nice to have; but it **would** be nice :)

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the close notification is for? Are you asking for a friendlier / different / expanded close notification?

Comment: @yannis rizos friendlier, and different

Answer (score 2):

There is already the predefined explanation of the close reason that is always displayed. For an off-topic question this is something like this (depending on the site):

> Questions on Skeptics - Stack Exchange are expected to relate to
>   scientific skepticism within the scope defined in the FAQ. Consider
>   editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you
>   believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read
>   more about closed questions here.

This covers exactly what you're proposing to add as an automatic message. The value of those additional comments many users post when closing is that they can be more specific and targeted towards that one question. The close reason has to be very general, your comment can be specific to that one question, and you can suggest ways to edit it to make it suitable for reopening.

That is something you can't automate, for a general explanation the close reason provides enough information in my opinion.

Comment: I guess my question was phrased poorly. It would be nice if the off topic message could contain a concise version of the FAQ. Obviously the OP didn't read the FAQ before posting, and in my experience putting a comment explaining what IS on topic helps.

Comment: @Joe The on-topic/off-topic part of the FAQ is longer than the comment limit on most sites, I don't think a general notice can succinctly explain that. That is something we still need to do manually, as we can quote only the relevant part of the FAQ, unlike an automatic notice.

Comment: The windows phone FAQ can be summed up as `this site is for enthusiasts, power users, and regular people who use the Windows Phone operating system and the problems they face.` well, maybe that is just clear to me as I helped write it :p Can't other sites be just as concise?